# Checking for known UIViewcontroller references

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, casting

I have a storyboard based app. Inside the storyboard I define a modal segue where a UINavigationController containing a UVviewController is presented. During the `prepareForSegue` method the code is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)destinationViewController;
        UIViewController *topController = navController.topViewController;
        if ([topController isMemberOfClass:[FilterBaseViewController class]]) {
            FilterBaseViewController *filterController = (FilterBaseViewController *)topController;
            filterController.dismissalDelegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

As shown above, I do quite a lot of checks to make sure that each controller I get access to is **actually** the controller I am looking for. But my code has become wordy. Knowing the layout of my storyboard couldn't I just say:

```
UIViewController * topController = ((UINavigationController *)destinationViewController).topViewController;
((FilterBaseViewController *)topController).dismissalDelegate = self;
```

knowing that my casts are correct and that the instances I get do belong to the required classes? Would there be any occasions that all the previous checks are indeed needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will add more than one segue form that controller to another you will receive crash. If I were you I would check segue identifier only. Checking class types are useless.

```
NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;
if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Edit"]) {
    UIViewController * topController = ((UINavigationController *)destinationViewController).topViewController;
    ((FilterBaseViewController *)topController).dismissalDelegate = self;
}
```